# Drag and drop RealmResults

Tags: android, realm, android-recyclerview

Sorry for my english. I have recyleView, in adapter i have `RealmResults`. I try do drop and down list, but when i replace List to `RealmResults` i have error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is not supported by 'RealmResults' or 'OrderedRealmCollectionSnapshot'.
```

This is my code:

```
ItemTouchHelper.Callback _ithCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                try {
                    Collections.swap(categoryPresenter.getCategory(), viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
                    categoryAdapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.toString());
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {}

            @Override
            public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                hideOpenedItems(recyclerView);
                return makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG,
                        ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RealmResult` is not a list and hence you cannot swap the items in `RealmResult`.

What you can do is

```
List<MyItem> list = realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults);
```

But, this will make the list unmanaged, which means if you update the data in the database, the objects will not be updated automatically.